# Can I implement in-app subscription without using google's play in-app billing in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I wanted to create an android app with subscription using flutter, and Im not going to upload it in playstore. Is there other way to implement in-app subscription without using google play in-app billing?

Answer (score 0):

I think, in case you're not gonna upload it to Google Play, you're free to pick whatever payment methods you like. E.g. Google Pay, Paypal, etc. The point is, you have to manage the billing flow, user system, subscription status all by yourself.